# MongoDB - Rename fields in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, rename

This is the document I get after an aggregation query:

```js
{
  _id: <some id>,
  name: 'xxxx',
  sales: {
    saleDate: 'dddddd',
    saleValue: 9999
  }
}
```

I need to rename the `sales` field to `sale`, I know I can use a projection at the end of my aggregation pipeline like this:

```js
[
  //... other aggregation stages before,
  {
    $project: {
      sale: '$sales'
    }
  }
]
```

But the problem with that approach is that now I have to specify all the remaining fields in the projection otherwise I will get only the `sale` field in the response, in this example I only have 3 fields but in my project I have much more than that.

So is there another way to rename a field in an aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  $set: {
    sale: '$sales'
    sales: '$$REMOVE'
  }
}
```